# authorize-security-group-ingress not adding rule to security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

Created a AWS security group:

```
aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name test-sg --description "test"
```

Showed the output as:

```
{
"GroupId": "sg-79e9441d"
}
```

Added a new rule to it:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name test-sg --port 8091 --protocol tcp
```

Described the group as:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-name test-sg
```

The output does not show the rule in the security group:

```
{
 "SecurityGroups": [
    {
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [
            {
                "IpProtocol": "-1", 
                "IpRanges": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ], 
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                "PrefixListIds": []
            }
        ], 
        "Description": "test", 
        "IpPermissions": [], 
        "GroupName": "test-sg", 
        "VpcId": "vpc-c561f9a0", 
        "OwnerId": "598307997273", 
        "GroupId": "sg-79e9441d"
    }
]
}
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `--cidr` option which says from what IP range you want to accept the traffic.

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name test-sg --port 8091 --protocol tcp --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
```

See: [authorize-security-group-ingress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html)